# Why am I getting different results when I run this with the print statement commented out?

Tags: c

I'm working through some online courses for c and I'm finding a very odd result. In the below function I get the correct answers when I uncomment the printf statement at the bottom. However when I run the fuction without the printf() I get seemingly random results.

I am printing out this result in another function. I gather it may be something to do with not defining the array as its using trash values, but I am then going through and setting each of these in the loop.

```
string ciphercalc(string text, string key)
{
    int length = strlen(text);
    char characters[length + 1];
    characters[length + 1] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] < 65 || (text[i] > 90 && text[i] < 97) || text[i] > 122 )
        {
            characters[i] = text[i];
        }
        else if (text[i] < 95)
        {
            if (key[i] < 95)
            {
                characters[i] = key[i];

            }
            else
            {
                characters[i] = key[i] - 32;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (key[i] > 95)
            {
                characters[i] = key[i];

            }
            else
            {
                characters[i] = key[i] + 32;
            }
        }
    }

    string endchar = characters;
    //printf("%s", endchar);
    return endchar;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Short of knowing exactly how `string` is implemented, there's not much we can do. It's not a standard C thing.

Comment: @lordf This is a very bad code with undefined behavior. Do not use such a course.

Comment: `characters[length + 1] = '\0';` This is writing 1 char beyond the allocated size, and that's only the first of several problems.

Comment: @dxiv is it? I have defined the size as length +1 and then given length +1 value as '\0'. Am i missing something?

Comment: @lordf Indexes start at `0` in C. The (valid) elements in your array are from `characters[0]` to `characters[length]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return a pointer to local variable from a function. Memory used to store local variables is automatically freed when function exits and might be re-used by other functions.

Allocate the memory dynamically:

```
char* characters = malloc(length + 1);
```

and free when no longer needed (possibly in another function):

```
free(characters)
```

Or, pass the output array to your function alongside your input arguments:

```
void ciphercalc(string text, string key, char* characters, int max_characters)
```

your function has to make sure ouptut array is big enough before writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Returning pointer to local variable 'characters' that will be invalid when returning.

Comment: Thats a little over my head. I'm just getting started with C. I think what you're saying is that the when I print this returned value "endchar" it doesn't carry the location of "characters" with it so its effectively undefined?. When I uncomment the print function it stores the values for enchar and can then be retrieved when i use this returned value?

Comment: the returned value endchar is pointing to the characters but when you return from ciphercalc characters no longer exists. you're pointing somewhere in the stack memory that could have anything. the printf call just randomly changes the alignment of things in stack memory so it works by accident. google automatic variables vs static variables

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. I'll have a read.

Answer (score 0):

```
char characters[length + 1];
characters[length + 1] = '\0';
```

The index of array `characters` that you can access is from `0` to `length` not `length + 1`.

Because in the `for` loop, you use `characters[i]`, with `i` from `0` to `26`, you have to add another condition if `length < 26`:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 26 && i < length; i++) {...}
```

Then out of `for` loop, at the null character to string at `i` position:

```
characters[i] = '\0';
```

OT, i guess you use string with `CS50` libraries. I recommend you using either `char` pointer (`char * text`) or character array (`char text[]`) for string in C.

As the answer of @BilMorgan, return the local value is not recommended. You should use `characters` as the argument of the function, or you can use the pointer of character:

```
char * characters = malloc(length + 1);
if(!characters) {return NULL;}
```

The return it at the end of this function. Note that, you do not to declare new string `endchar` as you did in your code. `return characters;` is enough.

Your code can be as below:

```
char * ciphercalc(char  *text, char *key) 
//  OR you want to use string type: char * ciphercalc(string  text, string key)
{
    size_t length = strlen(text);
    char *characters = malloc(length+1);

    //verify the return value of malloc function
    if(!characters) {return NULL;}
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26 && i < length; i++) {
       // your code
    }

    characters[i] = '\0';
    return characters;
}
```